# <img> tag not working with local source path

Tags: php, html, css, database, image

I want user to upload profile pic where I am storing image name into database and image into local images folder which is also in the same directory as the code is in. After uploading is done i want to display the same image. I am using code given below but its not working

```
<img src="images/".$row["profilepic"] width="200" height="200">
```

but when I try to display same picture using absolute path it is working fine

```
<img src="images/-226060409.jpg" width="200" height="200">
```

can somebody help me in fixing this issue?
note: everything is running on local machine using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Do you display the image with `echo`?

Comment: yup  <?php echo $profile_pic; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
src="images/".$row["profilepic"]
```

to:

```
src="images/' . $row['profilepic'] . '"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your img name is appearing outside of the ending src quote. I'm seeing this, src="images/"-226060409.jpg and should read src="images/-226060409.jpg". You can view your page source code to identify problem.